# Python: Iterate an operation across different columns of one row for all rows of a graphlab.SFrame

Tags: python, loops, graphlab, sframe

There is a SFrame with columns having `dict` elements.

```
import graphlab
import numpy as np
a = graphlab.SFrame({'col1':[{'oshan':3,'modi':4},{'ravi':1,'kishan':5}],
                     'col2':[{'oshan':1,'rawat':2},{'hari':3,'kishan':4}]})
```

I want to calculate `cosine` distance between these two columns for each row of the SFrame. Below is the operation using `for loop`.

```
dis = np.zeros(len(a),dtype = float)
for i in range(len(a)):
    dis[i] = graphlab.distances.cosine(a['col1'][i],a['col2'][i])

a['distance12'] = dis
```

This is very inefficient and would take hours if the number of rows was large. Could someone please suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can usually avoid looping over an SFrame by using the `apply` function. In your case, it would look like this:

```
a.apply(lambda row: graphlab.distances.cosine(row['col1'], row['col2']))
```

That should be significantly faster than looping in Python.